# FileSystemStorage не сохраняет файл

Tags: python-3.x, django, nginx

Cтолкнулся с мистической проблемой в django.
Есть ajax форма через которую отправляется архив (.zip/.rar) и некое текстовое описание. Проблема в том, что этот архив не всегда сохраняется на серваке.
Так вот, обработка архива делится на два этапа

```
try:
    file = request.FILES['archive']
except BaseException:
    error = 'Забыл закинуть архив!'
```

Первый: Архив распакуется в определенную директорию, тут проблем вообще нет.

```
   tmp_file = file.file.name 
   if file.split('.')[-1] == 'rar':
        os.system('unrar e {} {}'.format(tmp_file, final_dir))
    elif file.split('.')[-1] == 'zip':
        os.system('unzip {} -d {} -x "__MACOSX/*"'.format(tmp_file, final_dir))
```

Второй: делается бэкап этого архива, и вот тут-то и проблема, он не всегда создается

```
try:
    fs = FileSystemStorage(location=final_dir)
    fs.save('source.%s' % file.name.split('.')[-1], file)
except BaseException as e:
    logger.error('Ajax save backup %s' % e)
```

Бэкап сохраняется в ту же директорию, куда он и распакуется. Проблема в том, что с распаковкой все всегда отлично, а вот бэкап, почему-то не всегда сохраняется, без каких либо ошибок. Пробовал shutil.copy(...), та-же хня.

Понимаю еслиб он вообще не сохранялся, но он то сохраняется, то нет...

В конце скрипта стоит проверка на бэкап, он не ругается, значит бэкап сохраняется и со временем мистическим образом исчезает

```
if not os.path.isfile('{}/source.{}'.format(final_dir, file.name.split('.')[-1])):
    logger.error('Ajax save backup no source')
```

Может у кого есть мысли по этой проблеме?

Запуск отдельного потока для обработки файлов из архива (запускается в самом конце вьюхи, перед return HttpResponse(....)):

```
subprocess.Popen(['/opt/env/bin/python', '{}manage.py'.format(settings.PROJECT_DIR), 'archive_processing', str(chapter.id)], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
```

Comment: Что делает `manage.py`?

Comment: /var/www/django_project/manage.py, файл, через который в джанге запускаются все консольные скрипты. с помощью него, запускаю консольный скрипт archive_processing и передаю в него id главы (chapter.id)

Comment: Что делает `archive_processing`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема решается путем сохранения архива из FILES в директорию с последующей распаковкой, тогда сохраняется бэкап.

Насчет исчезновения: Походу django автоматически удаляет файл спустя несколько секунд из /tmp/ (FILES) после первого взаимодействия с ним.

**Второй раз дергать один и тот-же файл из FILES не советую**

Comment: Тогда можно было попробовать вынести файл в конструкцию `with` 
https://pythonworld.ru/osnovy/with-as-menedzhery-konteksta.html . Рад, что разобрались